# Click and keydown at same time for draggable jQuery event?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, keydown

I'm trying to have a jQuery UI event fire only if it meets the criteria of being clicked while the shift key is in the keydown state ( to mimic being held), and if not disable the event.

This example uses jQuery UI's `.draggable` to drag a container div only if the user clicks and holds shift.

http://jsfiddle.net/zEfyC/

Non working code, not sure if this is the best way to do this or what's wrong.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

    $('.container').keydown(function() {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            $('.container').draggable();
        } else {
            $('.container').draggable({
                disabled: true
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see lots of errors with that code.  Firstly, you only add the key listener after there's been a click on the document.  Second you are adding keydown to the container div, rather than the whole document.  Then, you also need to listen to keyup, since releasing the shift key should disable draggability, then you also need to pass disabled: false to the case where shift is down.  And your handler is missing the `e` parameter. Try this:

```
$(function(e) {
    var handler = function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            $('.container').draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
        } else {
            $('.container').draggable({
                disabled: true
            });
        }
    };
    $(document).keydown(handler);
    $(document).keyup(handler);
});
```

Comment: Works fine in simple demo so thanks, the code was messed up, but in the real usage it still causes weird problems, for one draggable.png images for some reason become more opaque when shift is released, and it also disabled other non related draggable events on the page.

Comment: I think that's due to CSS styles applied by jQuery UI when it makes an item a draggable, or disables a draggable item.  You can probably override those (either by telling jQuery to use a different class or by defining your own styles on the element)

Comment: wow your right, it is applying `opacity: .35;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=35);` , other issue was resolved, I guess I have to over-ride it.