# jquery: click and move selected div with keydown

Tags: jquery

I am able to obtain the attributes of the 'div' when I clicked on the 'div'. However I am unable to pass the attributes down to the second part which is the Keyboard events.

May I know how can I move the 'div' I clicked with Keydown?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        getClass = "'."+this.className+"'";
        //alert(getClass);
        $(document).keydown(function(key) {
            switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
                case 65:
                    $(getClass).animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                    //alert(getClass);
                    break;
                case 83:
                    $(getClass).animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                    break;
                case 87:
                    $(getClass).animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                    break;
                case 68:
                    $(getClass).animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                    break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you kind soul in advance.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899466/click-and-keydown-at-same-time-for-draggable-jquery-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is perfect. Few changes I made and it worked for me

```
$("div").click(function() {
    getClass = "."+this.className+"";
    //alert(getClass);
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        switch (charCode) {
            case 37:
                $(getClass).animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 38:
                $(getClass).animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 39:
                $(getClass).animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            case 40:
                $(getClass).animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
            default:

            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Changes I made.

1) Remove quotes from this.className

2) use event instead of key(optional)

3) keycode for arrow keys are different than you specified.

Give css to you div to see if it works

```
<style>
    div{
        padding:2px;
        border:2px;
        background: #eee;
        top:10px;
        left:10px;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```