# dragging an element with middle mouse button

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to drag an element with the middle mouse button. I'm using jQuery, and by default, the drag event is set to the left mouse button. I found a seven years old ticket on [jQuery UI](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6909) where a guy asks to implement the which option in the draggable object. It seems it wasn't implemented, but the guy has a [working demo](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/which) (it's right mouse button in the demo) with the modified jQuery file. Now I don't want to modify jQuery source code.

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899466/click-and-keydown-at-same-time-for-draggable-jquery-event), they manage to make the drag work when the user does <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT MOUSE BUTTON</kbd>. I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629980/jquery-draggable-enable-and-disable) that explains how to enable/disable a drag event.

Is there a way to middle mouse drag with jQuery?

The following code only allows me to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT MOUSE BUTTON</kbd>, but that's not the desired result. I can't figure out how to start the drag when the user uses middle mouse button.

```
$(function(e) {
    var handler = function(e) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            $('.objects').draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
        } else {
            $('.objects').draggable({
                disabled: true
            });
        }
    };
    $(document).keydown(handler);
    $(document).keyup(handler);
});
```